# How do I configure password encoder over WS-Security with Spring-Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, ws-security

I have a Spring-Boot project that produces a SOAP web service. I configure it to use WS-Security (Wss4jSecurityInterceptor). The users are being loaded from database (MySQL) using JdbcUserDetailsManager. Furthermore I encrypt the user password using BCryptPasswordEncoder.

But when I try to consume the web service I get "The security token could not be authenticated or authorized; nested exception is org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized".

I know that Spring-Boot is trying compare plain text password with encrypt password at the data base. When I save the password on plain text in the data base it work!

How do I configure password encoder over WS-Security with Spring-Boot?

Github project:  https://github.com/saenzemiliano/spring-boot-example-ws-wss.git

Web service location
http://localhost:8080/sample/ws/countries

Web service invocation

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gs="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-D3BE54CA98BF76B3BF15548134030756">
            <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">secret</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <gs:getCountryRequest>
         <gs:name>Uruguay</gs:name>
      </gs:getCountryRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

web service result

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">The security token could not be authenticated or authorized; nested exception is org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not posible, `org.apache.wss4j.*` doesn't support password encoding.
`UsernameTokenValidator.java` compare original password with candidate password using `equal(...)`.

BUUUUUUTTTT!!!! You can implement another UsernameTokenValidator and set it at Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.

Wss4jSecurityInterceptor:

```
    @Bean
public AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor(){
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    securityInterceptor.setValidationActions("UsernameToken");
    securityInterceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(securitySpringBootCallbackHandler());
    WSSConfig wssConfig = WSSConfig.getNewInstance();
    wssConfig.setValidator(WSConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN, AppUsernameTokenValidator.class);
    securityInterceptor.setWssConfig(wssConfig);
    return securityInterceptor;
}
```

asfsdf

```
protected void verifyDigestPassword(UsernameToken usernameToken,
                                    RequestData data) throws WSSecurityException {
    if (data.getCallbackHandler() == null) {
        throw new WSSecurityException(WSSecurityException.ErrorCode.FAILURE, "noCallback");
    }

    String user = usernameToken.getName();
    String password = usernameToken.getPassword();
    String nonce = usernameToken.getNonce();
    String createdTime = usernameToken.getCreated();
    String pwType = usernameToken.getPasswordType();
    boolean passwordsAreEncoded = usernameToken.getPasswordsAreEncoded();

    WSPasswordCallback pwCb =
        new WSPasswordCallback(user, null, pwType, WSPasswordCallback.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    try {
        data.getCallbackHandler().handle(new Callback[]{pwCb});
    } catch (IOException | UnsupportedCallbackException e) {
        LOG.debug(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new WSSecurityException(
            WSSecurityException.ErrorCode.FAILED_AUTHENTICATION, e
        );
    }
    String origPassword = pwCb.getPassword();
    if (origPassword == null) {
        LOG.debug("Callback supplied no password for: {}", user);
        throw new WSSecurityException(WSSecurityException.ErrorCode.FAILED_AUTHENTICATION);
    }
    if (usernameToken.isHashed()) {
        String passDigest;
        if (passwordsAreEncoded) {
            passDigest = UsernameToken.doPasswordDigest(nonce, createdTime,
                                                        Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(origPassword));
        } else {
            passDigest = UsernameToken.doPasswordDigest(nonce, createdTime, origPassword);
        }
        if (!passDigest.equals(password)) {
            throw new WSSecurityException(WSSecurityException.ErrorCode.FAILED_AUTHENTICATION);
        }
    } else {
        if (!origPassword.equals(password)) {
            throw new WSSecurityException(WSSecurityException.ErrorCode.FAILED_AUTHENTICATION);
        }
    }
}
```

Error trace:

```
org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.UsernameTokenValidator.verifyDigestPassword(UsernameTokenValidator.java:180) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.UsernameTokenValidator.verifyPlaintextPassword(UsernameTokenValidator.java:129) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.UsernameTokenValidator.validate(UsernameTokenValidator.java:89) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleUsernameToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:169) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:62) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.engine.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:340) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.validateMessage(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:682) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.handleRequest(AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.java:124) [spring-ws-security-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:227) [spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176) [spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:89) [spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61) [spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293) [spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure password encoder bean:

```
@Configuration

 public class PasswordEncoderConfig {



@Bean

public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

    return new PasswordEncoder() {

        @Override

        public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {

            return rawPassword.toString();

        }



        @Override

        public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {

            return rawPassword.toString().equals(encodedPassword);

        }

    };

}
}
```

Comment: I try this, but It not work. Furthermore I need encrypt my passwords, so I use BCryptPasswordEncoder algorithm.

Comment: Yes you can use any algorithm bcrypt, md5 in some bean return instance of Bcrypt

Comment: I implement the class AppPasswordEncoder.java. If you want you can test to use BCryptPasswordEncoder. It does not work. It work only when I use plain text password.

Comment: Run command:
mvn -P dev spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev

Comment: I don't know why, but password encoder you work over a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter project. I am working over a WsConfigurerAdapter project.